# what is response in success: function(response) in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

I am not sure if i am doing it correct. I am passing a url for ajax 'GET' request and URL has the some query parameters(?abc='a'). But when i do console.log(response) in  success: function(response){console.log(response)}.the response does not contain abc value.

Comment: Could you provide the code in question? It's way easier to answer if we have some code to look at.

Comment: Why would you expect the **response** to contain **request** parameters?

Comment: *"what is response in success: function(response) in ajax"* [This is perfectly well explained in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax).

Comment: We have no idea what you do with those query params at server or what server is returning. Those params will not be part of response without server side script including them in some way. Please show all relevant code

Answer (score 0):

I will show you an example to show with ajax on the console data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //this the DOM
    $(function(){

        $('body').on('click', '.action_button', function() {
            $x = {
                key:'show',
                values:$('.values').val()
            }; $.post('ajax.php', $x, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        });

    });
</script>


<?php 
    //your php file in ajax.php (another file)
    $key = $_POST['key'];

    switch ( $key ) :
        case 'show' :
            $values = $_POST['values'];
            echo $values;
        break;
    endswitch;
 ?>
```

HTML IS HERE

```
<input type="text" class="values" placeholder="Give me some values">
<input type="button" class="action_button" value="Click me for show the links">
```